# Grails jQuery icons not showing up

Tags: jquery, grails

application.css

```
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom
*= require_tree .
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require bootstrap

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
// plugins for the compile step
compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
compile ':cache:1.1.8'
compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
compile ":mail:1.0.7"
compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"


// plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.1'
```

in gsp

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Appointments </title>
<g:javascript>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            hide: "puff",
            show: "slide",
            height: 200,
            width: 425,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            },
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center"
            }
        });
    });            
</g:javascript>
<style>
    .ui-widget-header, .ui-state-default, ui-button {
        background: #FFE6E6;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        color: #000000;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

and also in .gsp

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <div id="dialog" title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Success!!!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
        <p>${flash.message}</p>
    </div>     
</g:if>
```

The icon that is an "x" that goes in the dialog box close button in the top right corner does not appear.

Comment: Have you looked into your security setting? Is there anything preventing jQuery icnos to show up. Find the image that has the icons and type the image path in your browser and see if it shows up.

Comment: Are the images not appearing? or you are seeing any broken images??

Comment: Images are not appearing. I'm not getting anything that the image is broken. In Config.groovy  springsecurity staticRules  I have      '/assets/**': ['permitAll'] and added '/assets/themes.ui-lightness/images/**':['permitAll']

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out I had to add to my gsp's that popped up the dialogs the tag

```
<jqui: resources />
```

I'm getting the icons now.